# How to use the nessesary conditions for optimality obtained via Lagrange multipliers?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization

I dont really see how we use the nessesary condition obtained via Lagrange multipliers.

The only way I see this is usefull is if we can find all points such that the Lagranian is zero and then compare them. But I dont see how we can find all such points in general.

Is this a problem or I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are "missing" (or really not missing, evidently) is that textbook and classroom examples disproportionately show the "few" instances in which it is possible to analytically solve the Lagrange multiplier necessary conditions.

In "real-life", this is quite often not the case, and numerical methods must be used to solve the optimization problem.  Many constrained nonlinear optimization numerical methods essentially involve iteratively numerically solving the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker (KKT) conditions (the generalization of Lagrange multipliers to handle inequality and equality constraints) while "rolling down hill" (line search or trust region to ensure objective function or combined metric of objective function and infeasibility is improving).  In essence, numerically solving the KKT conditions while heading in the direction toward a (local) optimum.